# AWS Codebuild node version update not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, version, aws-codebuild

I am getting an error while deploying my site

```
Minimum Node version not met :(

You are using Node v12.22.2. We require Node >=14 or up!
```

tried updating `buildspec.yaml` file with node update commands `npm install -g node`,
[image: Buildspec.yaml]

Comment: Can you show the contents of the buildspec file?

Comment: file added in the question

Comment: Did you try using `nodejs: latest` instead of `nodejs: 14.15.1`
Also, `nodejs` version is a child node of `runtime-versions:`. Hope it is correctly set.

Answer (score 4):

Try running `n 14.18.3`.

The [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package is pre-installed on (at least some) CodeBuild runtimes which you can use to install another version and select among installed versions.

[Details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776779/17977621)

Answer (score 4):

The default AWS linux container used by CodeBuild only supports nodejs version 12.x, so change it to the ubuntu image `aws/codebuild/standard:5.0` that supports node version 14.x

See [AWS Available Runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) for nodejs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have spaces in your `runtime-versions`, it looks like `runtime - versions` instead of `runtime-versions`, could it be just this?